# sql combining count with other fields

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider a scenario:

```
id    name  info  done
-----------------------
1     abc    x      0
2     abc    y      1   <-- I have this id
3     pqr    g      1
4     pqr    h      0
5     pqr    i      1   <-- I have this id
```

I have id for the last entry of every name.

The result I'm expecting consists of 2 things:

1. info for last entry of the name
2. number of done [having value 1] for that name

(1) can be easily achieved by `select info from table where id = myid`

But how can (2) be achieved in the same query? Can it be achieved in the same query?

Something like

```
select info, count(done) from table where id = myid group by name where ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, but can be done using conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when t.id = myid then info end), sum(done)
from table t
where t.name = (select name from table t2 where t2.id = myid);
```

The key is getting all the rows for the given name.

If you had multiple columns, then a correlated subquery might be the way to go:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.done) from table t2 where t2.name = t.name) as numdone
from table t
where t.id = myid;
```

Comment: @Hemario's answer (as I currently see it) is not correct because the calculation of `done` is wrong.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you eloborate why you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Considering done is either 1 or 0 you could just get the sum and display that.

```
select info, sum(done) 
from table where id = mid 
group by info
```

EDIT:

```
select info, s
from table
inner join (
    select name, sum(done) as s
    from table
    group by name    
) as zzz on zzz.name = table.name
where id = myid
```

Comment: How will this give OP the number of "Done" for all records sharing the same name as `myid`?

Answer (score 2):

You could join the table back to itself on `name` to get this.

```
SELECT t1.myid, t1.info, sum(t2.done) as number_of_done
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 on t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.id = myid
GROUP BY t1.myid, t1.info
```

Comment: will group by t1.myid be required? since id are unique

Comment: Yes, since we are aggregating by `SUM(t2.done)` when you join the table to itself by `name` you will, essentially, blow out the number of records on `t1` by the number of matching names on `t2`. So we have to `sum` and `group by` to get it back to a single record with the correct number `done` records from `t2`

Comment: can you please tell whether your or Hemario's solution is better considering performance?

Comment: It depends on the execution path of sqlite for both queries. My guess, not knowing sqlite well, is that mine will be a bit quicker. The only reason I say that is that a more naive RDBMS might full execute Hemario's subquery first before joining to `table`. The way I've written it here, it will pick up the one record with the `myid`, find the matching records in `t2` by name, then do the aggregation on that much smaller resultset. I'm not saying that sqlite would do that with Hemario's to make it quicker, but its tough to say. They are essentially the same query.

Comment: Based on my understanding of the question, this answer is overly complicated, with a join and aggregation.

Comment: @JNevill as Gordon Linoff said, would join be required in this case? Please see his answer too

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to display with more detailed data, use a windowing function:

```
select info, count(done) over (partition by name) ...
```